# Compare two workbooks using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to compare two different Workbooks, one named "after" (which is up to date) and another called "before" and I wanted to highlight the differences so it would be easy to pin down what changed between the two.

Okay so after I tested it a bit I got stuck in an error

> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Here's the full code with added comments so you can follow my thought process:

```
Sub OpenCsv()
Dim zcf, FolderPath, after, before, shtAfter, shtBefore As String
Dim MotherWB As Workbook, MotherWS As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook, ws, worksheetz As Worksheet
Dim oneRange, aCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Answer As Integer
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer


'Sorts Things for MotherWB
Set oneRange = Range("A4:Z9000")
Set aCell = Range("F4")
oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Opens and sets both Workbooks with their respective sheets
FolderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
after = FolderPath + "\" + "after.csv"
before = FolderPath + "\" + "before.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open (after)
Set wb = Workbooks("after.csv")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("after")
Set MotherWB = Workbooks("before.xlsm")
Set MotherWS = MotherWB.Worksheets("before")

'Makes ws looks like MotherWS so we compare them
 With ws
    Columns("A:Z").AutoFit
    Selection.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range("A1:A9000"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=True, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=False
    Set oneRange = Range("A4:Z9000")
    Set aCell = Range("F4")
    oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    End With


'Questions if you want to compare both
Answer = MsgBox("Uma vez aberto o relatório deseja comparar os dois?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Comparar")

If Answer = 6 Then


'For each cell in after that is not the same in before, color it yellow
    For Each mycell In wb.ws(after).UsedRange
        If Not mycell.Value = MotherWB.MotherWS(before).Cells(mycell.row, mycell.Column).Value Then
            mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

        End If
    Next

  'Display a message box to demonstrate the differences
    MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(after).Select

End If

End Sub
```

It gets the error after I return 6 from the answer, saying what I stated above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is set as boolean and the msgbox will return a integer. Declare an integer and then use an if statement to put true/false in your answer variable. Something similar to below

```
Dim temp as integer

temp = MsgBox("Uma vez aberto o relatório deseja comparar os dois?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Comparar")

if temp = 6 then
    Answer = true
else
    Answer = false
endif
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I fixed it and I'll edit the code accordingly.
The error remains though.

Comment: The same I was before, the fact that I had the variable wrong didn't matter I guess.
It starts in the For Each segment after I return the number 6